Limits of Composite Functions: Khan Academy
I was solving a problem on the limits of composite functions on Khan Academy and it seems to me like the problem does not have enough information to solve it. The problem in question
The problem asks to find $\lim_{{x \to 0}} f(h(x))$ with the graphs of f and h given.
Graphs of f and h
The given answer is that the limit doesn't exist. However, I don't think there is enough information in the graphs to say that.
In order to find the limit, I used the following approach,
$$\lim_{{x \to 0}} f(h(x)) = L \iff L = \lim_{{x \to 0^-}} f(h(x)) = \lim_{{x \to 0^+}} f(h(x))$$
Finding $\lim_{{x \to 0^-}} f(h(x))$
$$\lim_{{x \to 0^-}} f(h(x)) = \lim_{{h(x) \to 1^+}} f(h(x)) \approx 2.7$$
Finding $\lim_{{x \to 0^+}} f(h(x))$
$$\lim_{{x \to 0^+}} f(h(x)) = \lim_{{h(x) \to 5^-}} f(h(x)) = ?$$
The image of the first graph only shows x values up to 4, so $\lim_{{h(x) \to 5^-}} f(h(x))$ cannot be determined.
Therefore, I am unable to say whether the $\lim_{{x \to 0}} f(h(x))$ exists or what it is.
Please let me know if I'm making a mistake somewhere.

I agree with you.

Agreed. We'd need to see the graph of f near x=5 to be sure

Since the other anwers are all clearly incorrect, "the limit does not exist" has to be the answer. But still, they should have provided enough information to see it directly.
